# How to read in a file, then place each struct within the file into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I need to read in a file, and then assign each struct-sized amount of characters to a part of a struct array.

So, the first thirty characters would be first, second thirty characters would be last, and the 9 characters after that would be the ssn. This would be the first student in the array. The second student would begin after the 69th character, the third student would begin after the 138th character, and so on.

In the file, there would be something along the lines of:
john\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0smith\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0123456789jack\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0myers\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0987654321

Which would convert to:

allStudents[0].first = john

allStudents[0].last = smith

allStudents[0].ssn = 123456789

allStudents[1].first = jack

allStudents[1].last = myers

allStudents[1].ssn = 987654321

Here's the current set-up:

```
struct student allStudents[1000];

struct student {
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    char ssn[9];
};

void findStudents() {
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    char *temp;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    fp = fopen("students.db","rt");

    while( ( temp[counter2] = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        for (i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
            strcat(allStudents[counter].first, temp);
            counter2++;
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
            strcat(allStudents[counter].last, temp);
            counter2++;
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++) {
            strcat(allStudents[counter].ssn, temp);
            counter2++;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: How are you writing the data to that file in the first place?

Comment: One problem with your code is that you do not allocate memory for the the `temp` pointer, so the attempt to store something in `temp[counter2]` will probably lead to a crash. Another problem is that your code calls `fgetc` once, reading one character, and then you have several loops doing something, that does not make sense. Note that each call to `fgetc` will only read a single character (one byte) from the file.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Not sure how specific you'd like me to get, but I wrote it with fopen, fseek, fwrite, then fclose.

Comment: @Elias Would placing fgetc inside the loop help?

Comment: So many problems....take a debugger and step through the code. It will show you all the things that are wrong.

Comment: Your approach reading one char at a time and calling `strcat` 30 times is very inefficient, and the algorithm is wrong anyway. Also you're reading into the memory `temp` points to, but `temp` points nowhere. Finally you don't check if `fopen`  succeeds. And there are most likely more errors elsewhere in your code you didn't show here.

Comment: generate a struct, similar to: `struct student { char firstName[31]; char lastName[31]; char ssn[10]; };  then, for each student, set the contents of the struct to all '\0', then call `fread() 30bytes into firstName then call `fread()` for 30 bytes for lastName then call `fread()` for 9 bytes for ssn  Then repeat, until EOF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many mentioned in comments, there are multiple problems there, starting from not allocating memory for `char *temp` to using char array of length 9 for storing 9 characters long number, leaving no room for terminating character.

Trying to make as little changes as possible, I would change `ssn` size in your structure from 9 to 10 so terminating character gets stored. Keep in mind that you could have used integer to store that data in there and it would be more efficient in terms of memory storage.

One other thing I would like to point out is your `struct student allStudents[1000]` array. You allocate immediately `1000 * sizeof(struct)` bytes even if you have only 2 records in your database. Better approach would be using a linked list perhaps. Or just having an array of struct pointers( `struct student *allStudents[1000]` ) which would initially take much less memory, but you would have to allocate memory for every new struct.

I am assuming you're not allowed to change your `students.db` file, but we still need to add that terminating character, so there will be 69bytes in a file for a single record and 70 bytes in a structure. If you are allowed, I suggest you to change it.

```
struct student {
    // max allowed first and last name length should be 29 to ensure a space for terminating character
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    char ssn[10];
}

struct student allStudents[1000];

void findStudents() {
    int counter = 0;

    // if you want to just read the file use "r" mode, if you're writing in it you can use "r+" or "w+", but there is no "rt" as far as I know
    FILE *fp = fopen("students.db", "r");

    // you should always check if file is opened
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("File not opened");
        return;
    }

    // allocate memory where you will store a single record read from a file
    // note -1 since your struct is now 70bytes large and a record in file is 69
    // and for that reason we are using calloc instead of malloc, since calloc fills allocated memory with zero
    char *temp = (char*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct student) - 1);

    // instead of using fgetc for reading a single character, it's better to use fread here
    // fread returns number of elements successfully read which should be 69 if everything is alright
    while( ( fread(temp, 1, sizeof(struct student) - 1, fp) ) == sizeof(struct student) - 1 ) {
        // copy the content we read into the structure
        // we copy only 69 bytes here, leaving the last byte of structure untouched
        // and it will be 0x00 (terminating character for your ssn)
        memcpy(&allStudents[counter], temp, sizeof(struct student) - 1);
        counter++;
    }

    // free the allocated memory and close the file since you won't be using them anymore
    free(temp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I would also suggest you to perhaps return the number of read entries from your `student.db` database.

I wrote this code in an assumption you cannot change `student.db`'s file structure, but if you are allowed, please do consider mentioned suggestions.